# Google Map UI Experience not available in api (borde, style)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

1. Google Search gives a perfect UI Experience, while I cannot able to bring the same in google api. please advise how to proceed.
2. I am using kml layer for borderline to country and states, but data is not perfect as google
3. I tried google embed map, But I don't know how to write the click event on the map, because the map is bind on I-frame.

i attached the image below from google maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv4UZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a feature request for this in the IssueTracker for Google Maps Platform. You can star this issue to get updates on it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/35816953